# String variable out of context for use in HTML output

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to understand why the variable `myUrl` is out of context in the example below. What's the best way to handle this situation? Are there alternatives? The code is C# in an ASP.NET page.

```
<% string myUrl = "http://www.website.com"; %>
<ul class="footerLinks">
    <li><a href="<%= myUrl %>/index.html">Home</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: "Out of context" means "out of scope"? What happens in your case? Your code snippet works for me. The "Home" list item does have href pointing to "http://www.website.com/index.html". I tested it on VWD Express 2010.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because the `<%=` is being rendered before the script component. If you set `myUrl` in the code behind (`Page_Load` or `Init` event) then it should come through into the page as you are expecting. Obviously, remove the variable declaration in the markup as well.

Comment: While that is a solution, it doesn't explain why the `string` declaration is out of scope when it is called upon in the `<li>` tag.

Comment: It's because the `myUrl` variable hasn't been defined when the renderer interprets the `<%=` markup. If the variable was defined but not initialised in the code behind, then I guess a NullReferenceException would ensue.

Answer (score 2):

First of all your string variable should be set to public at the Class level.

```
public String myUrl
```

Then you need to call the `DataBind() method` in the `Page_PreRenderComplete` event:

```
protected void Page_PreRenderComplete(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataBind();
}
```

Because `<%= expressions` are evaluated at render time.